# Is there a mechanism for manipulating a process like prctl(), but for forked/exec*()d processes?

Tags: c, linux, process

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0)`, but for other process, e.g. a child process, or one that was `exec`'d? The program below demonstrates that the dumpable flag is not inherited by a process that was `execv`'d.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct stat st;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s PROGRAM [ARGS...]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (stat("/proc/self/fd", &st)) {
        perror("stat");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("before: owner of /proc/self/fd: %d\n", st.st_uid);

    if (prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0) == -1) {
        perror("prctl");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (stat("/proc/self/fd", &st)) {
        perror("stat");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("after: owner of /proc/self/fd: %d\n", st.st_uid);

    if (execv(argv[1], argv + 1) == -1) {
        perror("execv");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

```
$ ./a.out /usr/bin/stat -c 'in execed process: %u' /proc/self/fd
before: owner of /proc/self/fd: 1000
after: owner of /proc/self/fd: 0
in execed process: 1000
```

The reason I want this is that I have a program which runs as a regular user and reads sensitive data (passwords) from stdin, and I don't want others to be able to read this process data from `/proc`. Is there some alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want others to be able to read this process data from `/proc`. Is there some alternative way to do this?

The contents of the per-process subdirectories in `/proc` are ordinarily owned by the effective uid and effective gid of the corresponding process.  The only [documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) condition in which that's different is when the process's `dumpable` attribute has a value different from 1.

> The reason I want this is that I have a program which runs as a regular user and reads sensitive data (passwords) from stdin

**If the program in question runs as a regular user *that you can choose***, then the easiest thing to do is to choose a for-purpose user with a private primary group. For the purpose of `/proc` access, that should be about as good as setting the process non-dumpable or running it as root.  Maybe better, if the process wants to be able to read from its own `/proc` entry.  This is pretty natural, too.  It does not, however, serve the *primary* purpose of turning off the `dumpable` flag -- i.e. to prevent the process from dumping core.

**If the program itself is under your control**, then you can simply modify it to issue an appropriate `prctl()` call.  I suppose that this is not your case.

Otherwise, **the program cannot be modified and must be runnable by arbitrary users**.  According to [the `prctl()` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html), there are four ways other than calling `prctl()` to cause a process's `dumpable` flag to be turned off:

> - The process's effective user or group ID is changed.
> - The process's filesystem user or group ID is changed (see
>                  credentials(7)).
> - The process executes (execve(2)) a set-user-ID or set-
>                  group-ID program, resulting in a change of either the
>                  effective user ID or the effective group ID.
> - The process executes (execve(2)) a program that has file
>                  capabilities (see capabilities(7)), but only if the
>                  permitted capabilities gained exceed those already
>                  permitted for the process.

These all describe situations in which the process is differently affected by access controls than ordinary processes started by the same user, which comes back around to my original suggestion of arranging for appropriate access control simply by controlling the user as which the program runs.  After all, who cares if a random user runs the program and is able to retrieve secrets that they themselves entered? An issue arises only if *other* people can be tricked into divulging secrets to the program.  But if you're considering this alternative then you've already rejected the easy option.

With the program ultimately being launched by a non-privileged user, changing its effective or filesystem credentials, even via a wrapper program, is not a viable alternative by itself.  You're left, then, with making the program SUID or SGID, or assigning it capabilities that you can rely on differing from the user's normal ones.  Note that the SUID / SGID target, if you go that way, does not need to be *root*; it just needs to be different from the user's own.  This does, however, return again to having a designated identity for the program to run as.

The capabilites option requires your system to support capabilities, of course.  If it doesn't then SUID / SGID is your only remaining option.  Both of these are controlled by attributes attached to the program binary in the filesystem, so they do not require you to modify the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the excellent answer of John Bollinger, a poorly documented alternative is to change owner of the program that is about to be executed to root, and remove read permission on the executable:

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/program
sudo chmod go-rw /path/to/program
```

Still, there will be no inheritance of the dumpable flag across `execve`, but the kernel will set the flag every time that program is executed.

`man 5 core` gives the following reasoning:

> This is a security measure to ensure that an executable whose contents are not readable does not produce a possibly readable core dump containing an image of the executable